# Is class-based syntax implementable for Vue.js 3 from the view point of TypeScript functionality?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I know that the class API was dropped in Vue 3. It means that there is will not class-based syntax out-of-the-box.

I don't know which kind of magic converts Vue classes written by TypeScript to valid Vue component's objects in [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component), but it leaves the hope that class-based syntax is still could be implemented in other libraries. The problem is just does TypeScript's decorators allow it or no.

Comment: So many reasons not to use decorators already...

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thank you for the comment. Would you please to give me some instances of link to the article?

Comment: There have been like 5 decorator proposals submitted for standardization, none have ever gotten to stage 3 and whatever does, if anything ever does, will likely be incompatible with the typescript implementation which is years old now. TS will of course update their implementation to match whatever he gets standardized if anything ever does and then your code will be incompatible until you fix it. Another proposal was submitted like 4 days ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/416) the class component is compatible with Vue 3 and it exposes also an API to work with new composition api using new decorators, dropping out some ones like `@component` and adding new ones such as `@Options`, for more details check also this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am glad that I still can use OOP syntax.

Comment: You're welcome, me i don't like OOP in JS but i love it when working with PHP and Java

Comment: I write in TypeScript, so almost of OOP functionality that available in PHP and Java available in TypeScript.